# Why my dictionary is not updating in Python?

Tags: python

I have below code,
The output is coming very weird.

```
wsman_invoke_attr = {}
l = [u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot3', u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot2', u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot1', u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot5', u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4']
w = []
k = {"a":w}
for i in l:
    wsman_invoke_attr["InstanceID"] = i
    w.append([wsman_invoke_attr])
    k["a"] = copy.deepcopy(w)

    wsman_invoke_attr.clear()
print k
```

The output is coming as `{'a': [[{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4'}]]}`
where as I am looking for

```
{'a': [[{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot3'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot4'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot2'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot5'}], [{'InstanceID': u'BIOS.Setup.1-1:Slot1'}]]}
```

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: The "fix" for the code is replacing `k["a"] = copy.deepcopy(w)` with `w = copy.deepcopy(w); k["a"] = w` but the better solution is to restructure to a list comprehension as per viraptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be doing a lot of things that are not necessary. Clearing the temporary dictionary and deepcopy are not necessary here. Here's a simpler solution:

```
instances = [[{'InstanceID': iid}] for iid in l]
k = {'a': instances}
```

As for the issue in your code - when you do `wsman_invoke_attr.clear()` you're still holding a reference to the dictionary you used before, so you're clearing all of them at the same time. Then you add a new name to all of them again.